# how to convert .mobi and epub to html and text in php

Tags: php

I have a bunch of EPUB books that I have to convert to MOBI if I get a Kindle.
I would like to know whether there will necessarily be any loss of detail (e.g. meta-data, layout info) during a conversion from EPUB to MOBI and vice versa, analogous to a conversion between MP3 and WMA? What happens when multiple conversions are applied consecutively, e.g. EPUB->MOBI->EPUB->MOBI->EPUB.
How bad will the information lose get?

Comment: Whenever you ask for "Do Y, Y, Z in PHP" for a task which PHP clearly does not have builtins - you probably should look for a command line tool or library. And the answer to your question depends on what said tools provide for.